# Read from and write to serial port using cat command

Tags: serial-port, cat, tty

I have a device at comport `/dev/ttyUSB1`. I want to write ***binary*** file (not encoded, not ASCII or anything) to serial port, and read from the same serial port (again just in ***binary***, not encoded or ASCII, pure binary) and write the read data into a file. The device on the `/dev/ttyUSB1` first need to read the entire file, then process it and send the processed version back to the host machine over the same serial port. So, what I am trying right now is

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB1 115200 | cat ./lena_grayscale.bmp  > /dev/ttyUSB1 | cat < /dev/ttyUSB1 > lena_processed.bmp
```

where the first command is to set the baudrate to 115200 (which is the same for the device), the second command is to initialize the write, and the third is to initialize the read. However, when I run this, it finished right after it completes the transmit from the host machine. So, the host machine cannot receive the processed file. Now, I have two questions:

1- Is `cat` sends and receives data in binary, or it encodes/decodes to something?
2- What I should do to successfully receive the processed file?

Thanks

Comment: How to use a shell command is not a programming question, nor on-topic for this site.